# Apache returning 403 status code

Tags: apache-http-server, http, http-status-codes

I'm basically having a basic HTML document and I am trying to link a JavaScript file and a .gif  file which is in a CSS file. However, I notice that the networks tab of my browser says that it encountered a 403 error while trying to fetch the file. How may I solve this problem? Take a view at the image below to see how it looks like.

[image: My screen]

Comment: Forbidden means just that - it is either a filesystem permission, or something in the webserver configuration.  Have you checked the permissions of /js and its contents, and loader.gif?  Does loader.gif have the same permissions as logo.png?

Comment: I haven't changed any permissions for any files, neither have I got any `.htaccess` files. If you wish to get any further information, feel free to request. Also, I'm using XAMPP.

Comment: I asked if you checked them, not if you changed them,

Comment: How would I do so on OS X? New to OS X. :/

Comment: I am not familiar with OSX but every OS I have seen lets you see permissions by looking at the properties of the file.

Comment: Yeah, but OS X doesn't. However, I found out that I need to upgrade my OS to the new firmware in order to gain access to that privilege. Apparently, as per Apple, file permissions are changed without the users knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It was an OS X Bug.

As per Apple, there was a bug which update file permissions unexpectedly. After I updated my system to the latest version, I was able to edit the file permissions. Thanks for your time everyone!